# C# Serializing object only returns the ID

Tags: c#, serialization

I have a class `workHour` that I'm trying to `serialize` but it only returns the `ID`
(i.e {id:1} )

```
public class WorkHour : DomainEntity<int>
{
    public virtual Day day { get; set; }

    [Key]
    public int id;

    [Required]
    public int dayId { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan startTime { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan endTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime created { get; set; }
    public bool deleted { get; set; }
}
```

The result of the object before serialized

```
|created  |{6/14/2017 4:23:50 AM}|
|day      |null|    
|dayId    |1|
|deleted  |false|
|endTime  |{04:23:50.5419087}|
|id       |0|
|startTime|{04:23:50.5419087}|
```

The result of return Json(result) is:

```
{"Id": 18}
```

Comment: show serialization code

Answer (score 1):

this code work fine but I don't have a parent class:

```
public class WorkHour //: DomainEntity<int>
    {
        //public virtual Day day { get; set; }

        [Key]
        public int id;

        [Required]
        public int dayId { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan startTime { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan endTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime created { get; set; }
        public bool deleted { get; set; }
    }


    public class Test
    {
        public void Main()
        {
            var o = new WorkHour()
            {
                created = DateTime.Now,
                dayId = 0,
                deleted = false,
                endTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2),
                startTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2),
                id = 0,
            };
            Console.WriteLine( Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(o));

        }

    }
```

[newtonsoft.json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/)

Comment: For anybody who is not familiar with `Newtonsoft.Json`, it won't be clear as to what `JsonConvert` is.